# Django, Role matching query does not exist

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

As the Title says,
The models for Role and Location both have data in them as it was inserted in the admin page and confirmed.
I get the same issue with Location instead of role if it is commented out.

```
DoesNotExist at /api/add/res/
Role matching query does not exist.

Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response 132.                     
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/speedy/hrdb/hrdb/api.py" in set 26.         
role=Role.objects.get(role_name=data['role']), 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method 127.                 
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get 334.                 
self.model._meta.object_name
```

here is the api

```
def set(request):
data = json.loads(request.body)
res = Resource.objects.get_or_create(
    title=data['title'],
    preferred_name=data['preferred_name'],
    last_name=data['last_name'],
    employstatus=data['employstatus'],
    employer=data['employer'], 
    role=Role.objects.get(role_name=data['role']), 
    location=Location.objects.get(name=data['location']), 
    workphone=data['workphone'], 
    mobile_phone=data['mobile_phone'],
    email=data['email'], 
    notes=data['notes'], 
    updated_by=data['updated_by'], 
    )
print res
return HttpResponse('"Submitted"', content_type='application/json')
```

here is the Model

```
class Resource(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    preferred_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    employstatus = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    employer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    role = models.ForeignKey('Role')
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location')
    workphone = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)


class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
class Role(models.Model):
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    role_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Ad this is the JS stuff

```
var data={}

$.each($('#addPersonnel').find('.form-control'), function(){
    var field = this.id,
        value = $(this).val()
        data[field] = value
}) 
//data from add resource model to database with success function
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/add/res/",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),

    success: function(response) {
        var successMessage = $('<div>').text('Successfully saved to database...').css('color', 'green');
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
            $('#submitresource').html('Added!').addClass('btn-success')
            $('.modal-body').append(successMessage);
            window.setTimeout(function() { 
            $('#addPersonnel').modal('hide'); }, 1000);
            console.log("yers")              
        },
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json"
```

And here is some more then. This is the HTML, the part relevant to the location and role

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="role" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Role</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <select class="form-control" id="role">
            </select>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="location" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Location</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <select class="form-control" id="location">
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

this is the drop down js stuff (note Employer works fine)

```
var data={}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('/api/new/emp/', function(response){

        $('#employer').empty()

        $('#location').empty()

        $('#role').empty()

     $.each(response.Employers, function(){
         $('#employer').append('<option value='+this+'>'+this+'</option>')
    })

        $.each(response.Locations, function(){
            $('#location').append('<option value='+this+'>'+this+'</option>')
    })

        $.each(response.Roles, function(){
            $('#role').append('<option value='+this+'>'+this+'</option>')
```

And this is the api stuff.

```
def addresddpop(request):
    data = {
        'Employers':[],
        'Locations':[],
        'Roles':[]
}

# Get a list of all employers
    for ddemp in Employer.objects.all():
        data['Employers'].append(ddemp.employer_name)

# Get a list of all locations
    for ddloc in Location.objects.all():
        data['Locations'].append(ddloc.name)

# Get a list of all roles
    for ddrol in Role.objects.all():
        data['Roles'].append(ddrol.role_name)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: What is the posted value for `data['role']`? And the model for `Role`?

Comment: included the role and location models

Comment: the data is supplied via a drop down selection box

Comment: That wasn't what souldeux asked. What data is the view actually receiving? Post the value of `data` as printed from within the view.

Comment: At this rate I might as well put the whole project on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ok world I fixed the issue.
Because I had spaces in my roles and location the dropdowns were the issue so I changed them a bit

```
var data={}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('/api/new/emp/', function(response){

        $('#employer').empty()

        $('#location').empty()

        $('#role').empty()


        $.each(response.Employers, function(){
            //$('#employer').append('<option value='+this+'>'+this+'</option>')
            $('#employer').append($('<option></option>').val(this).text(this))
    })

        $.each(response.Locations, function(){
            //$('#location').append('<option value='+this+'>'+this+'</option>')
            $('#location').append($('<option></option>').val(this).text(this))
    })

        $.each(response.Roles, function(){
            // $('#role').append('<option value='+this+'>'+this+'</option>')
            $('#role').append($('<option></option>').val(this).text(this))
```

I have left the old code in so you can see the fix

Answer (score 1):

I think one of two things is happening. Possibility one: the values you're posting for `Role` and `Location` don't match the format you expect. For instance, the label in the dropdown may be the `name` or `role_name` but the posted value may be the ID. You mentioned that those data points are selected with a drop-down - double-check the `value` attributes in your `option`s for that `select` to make sure they're really names and not IDs.

Or, your jquery function is setting `data['role_name']` and `data['location']` before a selection is made (or is failing to change the value if the selection is changed).

If you post the value of `data` we can figure out which one is the case, but I'm almost certain it's one of these two issues.

Comment: its odd as when you check the payload in the params all the data I input is there. 
{"title":"Mr","preferred_name":"Marvin","last_name":"Robot","employer":"Sirius","employstatus":"Permenant","role":"maniacally","location":"space","workphone":"","mobile_phone":"","email":"","notes":"","updated_by":""}